# Why is axios .post() method not getting to the promise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, server, axios

I am trying to use axios from my client to make a post request to my server, like this:

```
    var firstName = $('#first-name').val();
    var lastName = $('#last-name').val();
    var organization = $('#organization').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    var complete = false;
    if (firstName == "" || lastName == "") {
        $('#name-group').addClass('has-error')
    }
    var reqBody = {
        firstName,
        lastName,
        email,
        password
    };
    if (organization != "") {
        reqBody.organization = organization;
    }
    axios.post('/users', reqBody)
    .then(function (res) {
        console.log("hello");    
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

The post request is happening successfully, but it's never going into the `.then()` and printing "hello." What could be the cause for this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have issue with your request body. Can you please try to modify it as:

```
var reqBody = {
       "firstName": firstName,
       "lastName" : lastName,
       "email" : email,
       "password" :password
    };
```

whatever you are trying to pass in `reqBody` in your code is not a valid `JSON` or javascript object.

Comment: I fixed it to make it valid `JSON`, but it's still not getting to the promise.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the problem was that my `'/users'` route did not send anything back in the response. After I added an empty `.send()` in the route, the code in the promise was executed.